# variable string interpolation in scala

Tags: scala

It's pretty clear, from the [scala docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html), that you can use string interpolation:

```
val name = "James"
println(s"Hello, $name")  // Hello, James
```

But, is it also possible to do this, where the format e.g. `"Hello, $name"` is in a variable?

I've tried something like this:

```
val name = "James"
val fmt = "Hello, $name"
println(s fmt)
println(s(fmt))
```

But, so far, nothing works. Is it even possible?

Comment: What is this s?

Comment: I think `s` resolves to a function https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/StringContext.html

Comment: I see. You are referring to the macro prefix. No it doesn't work that way. The string literal has to be presented for the macro expansion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no easy way to get what you're after. For string interpolation to work, the compiler has to cut up the string literal into different parts and send them to `StringContext` for reconstruction. The compiler won't do that to a `String` variable.

It is possible to cut up `String` values yourself, and send them to `StringContext`, but you also need a way to translate a variable name (a `String`) into the correct value.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57117954/4993128) to a similar question for an example how this might be done.

Answer (score 0):

No this will not work in scala.

```
val name = "James"
val fmt = "Hello, $name"
println(s fmt)
println(s(fmt))
```

But you can do like below

```
println(s"$fmt")
OR
println(f"$fmt%s")
```

In string interpolation `s` always expects doubles quotes to be present as next character, SO s fmt or s(fmt) either will not work.

You can find more information here https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html